# Exchange potential for a non-interacting system

Tags: density-functional-theory

If I have a system of two "non-interacting electrons" and I want to mimic its density using another non-interacting system (KS system). Would the KS potential contain the exchange potential?

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community (sorry it took me so long to write that)! Thank you for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future! Have you figured out the answer to this question now? Please update us!

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions from the comments.